# How to use maps in Javascript in Karate Framework?

Tags: javascript, karate

I am trying to use maps inside a Javascript function, to store a JSON object so that I can add any custom key and value to that object per desire.

Basically I tried this piece of code to check map functionality

```
 * def sample =
   """
   function(){
    var map = new Map({foo: 'bar'});
    return map;
    }
   """

  * def res =  sample()
  * print res
```

But it is throwing me this error

> javascript evaluation failed: sample(), ReferenceError: "Map" is not defined in  at line number 2

My goal is to add some keys dynamically in my predefined JSON object.
`karate.merge` doesn't allow dynamic key as well.

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Karate Version: 0.9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Karate you should forget about Java. JSON **is** a Map.

```
* def sample =
"""
function(){
  var map = { foo: 'bar' };
  map.someKey = 'value';
  var someDynamicKey = 'baz';
  map[someDynamicKey] = 'ban';
  return map;
}
"""
```

Maybe you should take some time to read the docs and [examples](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/js-arrays.feature).

Comment: Could you please explain a bit the below line.
 map[someDynamicKey] = 'ban';

Comment: that's normal JS. it will evaluate to `map['baz'] = 'ban';`. so the JSON `map` will become: `{ foo: 'bar', baz: 'ban' }`. ask someone near you who knows JS